# Why MySQL Connector/J DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType only supports TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Env: mysql-connector-java 8.0.19

JDBC spec defines three ResultSet types which are `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`(also default), `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`,  `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` and uses `DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType` method to indicate whether the specified ResultSet type is supported or not.

A quick look of `DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType` in MySQL JDBC implementation is:

```
public boolean supportsResultSetType(int type) throws SQLException {
    return (type == ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
}
```

The method above means it **only** supports `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, right?

But when the driver prepare statement, it uses `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` as default ResultSet type as JDBC spec defines:

```
// default result set type definition
private static final int DEFAULT_RESULT_SET_TYPE = ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY;

// prepare statement without explicit ResultSet type declaration 
public java.sql.PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
    return prepareStatement(sql, DEFAULT_RESULT_SET_TYPE, DEFAULT_RESULT_SET_CONCURRENCY);
}
```

How should I understand these two semantic conflict behaviors?

Comment: This is more suitable to report as a bug to MySQL/Oracle than to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm not sure it's a bug or not, so I start a question and wanna hear some advice from someone who is experienced. Now maybe I should report a bug to MySQL/Oracle, thanks.